# Java short date String convert to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, date, type-conversion, zoneddatetime

I have a `String` with a date in this format: `2021-10-05`. Need to convert this `String` to `ZonedDateTime` type. Tried to do it in this way, but the Text could not be parsed. Time can be 00:00:00. Any suggestions?

```
public static final ZoneId ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of("UTC");

ZonedDateTime dt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, //date String = 2021-10-05
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(ZONE_ID));
```

Comment: Did you mean to put 3 `M`s there? There should only be 2.

Comment: Oh... Yes, there should be 2 `M`. The problem is not with `M`. Editted. With this code I getting error: `Text '2021-10-05' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,UTC resolved to 2021-10-05 of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: Tip: Paste your exception message into your search engine. It goes much faster than waiting for an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `LocalDate` conversion first since there is no time to be parsed in the given string:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
ZonedDateTime dt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZONE_ID);
```

Or in a slightly more elegant way as posted in the comments:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
ZonedDateTime dt2 = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZONE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Since your date string is already in ISO 8601 format, you can simply parse it into a `LocalDate` without needing a `DateTimeFormatter` and then you can use [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) to convert the parsed value into a `ZonedDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.parse("2021-10-05").atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-05T00:00Z[UTC]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/V8RQ4t)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>